# Distribution of Ratio of 2 Chi-squared

Tags: probability, distributions, chi-squared-distribution

If the limiting distribution of $X_n \sim \chi^2(k)$ and $Y_n \sim \chi^2(j)$ would their ratio $X_n/Y_n$ also converge to a chi-squared limiting distribution, or would it follow the normal because of CLT?

Comment: One result about the ratio of two **independent** Chi-square distributed random variables is: let $X \sim \chi^2(k)$ and $Y \sim \chi^2(j)$, then $\dfrac{X/k}{Y/j}$ is $F(k,j)$-distributed.

Comment: How would the CLT apply to a sequence of *ratios* of random variables?

Comment: What's going to infinity here? $n$? $k$? $j$? Do $k$ and $j$ relate to $n$ somehow?

Answer (score 6):

With finite d.f.

- the ratio of two independent chi-squared variates has a beta-prime distribution (also sometimes called a 'beta distribution of the second kind').
- if you divide each of the chi-square variates by its df the ratio has an F-distribution.

Asymptotic arguments:

- if $j\to\infty$, you can apply Slutsky's theorem to argue that the F-ratio should go to a $\chi^2_k/k$
- if $k$ *also* $\to\infty$ you can in turn (with appropriate standardization) make an argument that invokes CLT