# If $X \sim a\chi_1^2$, and $Y \sim b\chi_1^2$, what's the distribution of $Z = X/Y$?

Tags: distributions

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$ a ratio of independent $\chi^2$ random variables with 1 degree of freedom. If $X \sim a\chi_1^2$, and $Y \sim b\chi_1^2$, what's the distribution of $Z = X/Y$? Is it a $\frac{a}{b}F_{1,1}$ distribution? Note that $a, b$ are real number constants.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate (with extension) of: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140876/distribution-of-ratio-of-2-chi-squared

Comment: @compbiostats They're similar questions but I don't think it can be a duplicate if it's an extension of another question. Or can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, exactly. $Z$ is $a/b$ times a random variable following an $F_{1,1}$ distribution or, in other words,
$$ \frac{b}{a} Z \sim F_{1,1}.$$

This follows immediately from the characterization of the $F$ distribution as the distribution of the ratio of two independent chisquare random variables, each divided by their degrees of freedom.

Also note that $$\frac{b}{a} Z = T^2$$ where $T\sim t_1$ or $T\sim$ Cauchy(0,1).

Answer (score 1):

You have two random variables, which are equivalent to Gamma random variables

$$X\sim a\chi^{2}_{1}\equiv\text{Gamma}(1/2,2a)$$
and
$$Y\sim b\chi^{2}_{1}\equiv\text{Gamma}(1/2,2b)$$

Then we define
$$Z=\frac{X}{Y}\sim B'\Big(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},1,\tfrac{b}{a}\Big)$$
where $B'()$ denotes the [generalized beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Generalization).